# Symfony3 - Relation Many-to-Many return string

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I try to access an attribute,with an Many-to-Many relation, but this one return a string value, so I can't use my function on this string value.
My entity :

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type_element_id", type="integer",nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\type_element", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $typeElement;
```

My html :

```
{{ element.typeElement.id }}
```

My error :

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a integer variable ("1").
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with :

```
  /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\type_element")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_element_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $typeElement;
```